# Why is it `<T>Type` as return type in Java Generics and not `Type<T>`?

Tags: java, generics, return-type, hamcrest

I just wrote a simple JUnit `Matcher` for `assertThat()` which requires *Generics*, of course.

By a bit of luck I found the right syntax for the **return type** of `static <T>Matcher not(Matcher<T> m)...`, although I don't understand why

- in the **return type** its `<T>Matcher` and
- in the **argument list** its `Matcher<T>`

**Why is it `<T>Matcher` in the return type?** What is the concept behind this?

I am coming from C++ and can handle its *Templates* there quite well. I know that *Generics* work differently, but that's why this is confusing to me.

Here is my own `Matcher` class. Look at the static helper `not`:

```
import org.hamcrest.*;

/** assertThat(result, not(hasItem("Something"))); */
class NotMatcher<T> extends BaseMatcher<T> {
    /** construction helper factory */
    static <T>Matcher not(Matcher<T> m) {  //< '<T>Matcher' ???
        return new NotMatcher<T>(m);
    }
    /** constructor */
    NotMatcher(Matcher<T> m) { /* ... */  }
    /* ... more methods ... */
}
```

Comment: Hint: Add a space between `<T>` and `Matcher`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis why? Does it help me to get a grip at the concept behind it?

Comment: Yup, exactly. That's not a return type. It's two separate things. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You really want

```
static <T> Matcher<T>
```

You need the first 'T' to declare the type for the generic method. The second 'T' is the type parameter for the Matcher class.

Comment: Oh! That is good. Why is my program working, then? What kind of matcher do I return here, then? Is it Java infering this by itself?

Comment: You are returning a 'raw type', which is allowed, but discouraged. You lose all the type safety. It's like using `List` instead of `List<String>`. Any generic methods in that class that use the type will just `Object` instead of `T`.

Comment: *"Any generic methods in that class that use the type will just Object instead of T"* ...which means that totally different overloads may be applied. Here it's the `not`-Method that now has an incorrect return type, which is passed to `assertThat()` -- which has several overloads, one of them also on `Object` (I assume). But because then `equals()` is called, it works again. Lucky me. Right?

Comment: @towi, basically, yes you got lucky ;)

Answer (score 12):

Towi I hope this illustration helps.

[image]

The above illustration is a direct response to the question's title: *Why is it `<T>Type` as return type in Java Generics and not `Type<T>`?*

There are several more additional points to consider in Towi's example, see comment trail.

Comment: Cool answer ^^ however, it should be mentioned that (a) the type parameter T declared by the method is hiding the class' type parameter T and (b) the return type Matcher in this case is a raw type.

Comment: @MichaelSchmeißer Thanks, I'll add a note in my answer and use your comment as a supplement. My answer was a direct response to the title: *Why is it `<T>Type` as return type in Java Generics and not `Type<T>`?*.

Comment: Hmm, actually, since the method is static, I have to revoke (a) - the Ts are not hiding each other in this case.

Comment: @MichaelSchmeißer "hiding T", of course. I should have written `static <U> Matcher not(Matcher<U> m)`. Or is it `static <U> Matcher not(Matcher<T> m)`? What is a "raw type"?

Comment: @Ronixus Gotya. `Matcher` is the return type, `<T>` the generic declaration. But why is the return type not dependent on a generic argument? `Matcher` gets a type argument `<T>`, so I would assume the return value, if it's a `Matcher` also depends on it. I guess I could declare `static <U,V> Matcher not(Matcher<U> u, Matcher<V> v)`? What kind of `Matcher` do I return? Maybe a new one `Matcher<Z>` or one of the others `Matcher<U>` or `Matcher<V>`...

Comment: Although your answer, and graphical skills too, is beautiful, @wolfcastle's answer helped me more in the understanding of the concept -- I got the connection to C++ :-)

Comment: Cool. That's what's great in SO, you'll get different answers and one will nail that "aha" connection. No worries buddy. Glad to help.